# Could not choose the accepted answer

Tags: discussion, support

Hi I'm in a situation that I could not choose which answer that I should
mark as accepted. This is regarding this question:
[Copper strips in chopper transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86634/copper-strips-in-chopper-transformer)

Because I'm so new into this industry and I'm clearly nobody to accept 
any answer from other. All three answers seems to be reasonable. What should
I do. Should I request some other person who is knowledgeable and higher skilled
to choose an accepted answer ? Could please help me in this.

[this is a different situation, because this is not a situation of , How to
fix it and yes you fix it and it works! Thanks I'll accept answer. Instead 
there is a theoretical background and different answers have reasonable 
weight of value there].

Comment: +1 for asking here. I missed that question but an unrelated tip is that photo is 3MP when the site scales to 630 pixels wide so try to crop the photo next time, sometimes that doesn't go across well and can cop a downvote. Plus it's well oversaturated and just about cooked my eyeballs when I opened it, photography of electronic bits can be tricky but it might be worth trying some different lighting I guess that was taken using a small on camera flash?

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to accept an answer right away, you can wait for votes to sort the answers and make your decision after some time.

You should only accept an answer if it solves your problem or doubt, otherwise it's better for everyone if you leave it "open": it encourages further contribution and development of the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have the answer to my question, I try to do one of the following

- Find the answer that provided all the help needed and "accept" that.
- Look for the answer that provided the majority of the help needed and "accept" that.
- Add my own answer and (after a short while), accept that.

If several answers all provide an equally acceptable answer to your question, I would accept the one that looks like it will be most helpful to future searchers. Usually this will be the most upvoted answer, but use your own judgement. I wouldn't worry too much about not being enough of an expert to make a "correct" judgement. You can always come back later and reassign your accepted answer in the light of a better understanding.

You do this community a service when you accept an answer because it removes the question from the list of unanswered questions. You get paid for this service in reputation points.

If you don't have the answer to your question, you should probably not accept the least-worst answer. It may help to leave comments explaining why an offered answer has not helped you realize the solution to the problem in your question.

I also upvote any and all answers that were of any help to me, even if I feel they didn't completely answer my question.